# Do I need "Multiplayer Compatibility" enabled in iTunes Connect in order for Game Center leaderboards to function globally?

Tags: xcode6, sprite-kit, app-store-connect, game-center-leaderboard

I have a functioning Sprite Kit Game Center leaderboard. Is it necessary to have "multiplayer compatibility" enabled if my game is not multiplayer, but has a global leaderboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, multiplayer has nothing to do with the leaderboard.